# How to store a functions return values and add them together

Tags: python-2.7

I need a place to store the return data from my addmassage() function to be referenced later. I want to do this without a global variable but is that possible? Here is some of my code.

```
def mainFunction():
      massageList = [0, 0, 0]
      """This function hosts the menu and """
      print "Make a selection:"
      print "1. Add a massage to my schedule"
      print "2. View my current schedule"
      print "3. Cancel a massage from my schedule"
      print "4. Calculate fundraising total"
      print "5. Quit"
      selection = raw_input("Your selection:")
      if selection == "1":
        addMassage1 = addMassage()
        massageList[0] = massageList[0] + addMassage1[0] 
        massageList[1] = massageList[1] + addMassage1[1] 
        massageList[2] = massageList[2] + addMassage1[2]
        print massageList
        mainFunction()
      if selection == "2":
        print massageList
        mainFunction()
    def addMassage():
      massageList = [0, 0, 0]
      massageType = raw_input("Add a (1) 15 minute, (2) 30 minute, or (3) 60 minute massage")
      if massageType == "1":
        massageList[0] = massageList[0] + 1
      if massageType == "2":
        massageList[1] = massageList[1] + 1
      if massageType == "3":
        massageList[2] = massageList[2] + 1
      return massageList

    enter code here
```

Comment: The indentation of your code seems a bit off, which for Python code can cause confusion... To try to address your question I would suggest looking into using objects and creating your own class to manage your massage list.

Answer (score 0):

You could output it to a separate file then have the program read it later but that could mess things up if you accidentally do something to the file...

Comment: Provide example of such.

Comment: #so store output, value, etc. in a variable.

Comment: then  do f = open('nameoffile.txt', 'w') then f.write(variablename) then f.close() this outputs the stored value to an external file named nameoffile.txt

Comment: you can then call it later by doing something like value = f.read() print (value). if the file gets moved calling it back to get your stored value can become tricky

Comment: Add this to your answer